# Data need to fetch another column from exiting column list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, development, designer-workflow

We had two list in SharePoint 2013. One list for report and list for access. First list "Report" consist of different column, one column name as "Request access" with Hyperlink column. So when user click on "Request access" column it will takes to "Access" list. Now our requirement, Access list columns data need to fetch from "Report" register list. Means "system" name, "request number", "owner names" need to come on "Access" list. Is there any code for my request instead of lookup column.

Hi, Jaitsujin, i am trying below code for "System" column data fetching but its not working. Could you please suggest or correct me where i am doing wrong.

Code:

$(function () {
        $('input[title*="system"]').on("change paste keyup", function() {
            var system = $(this).val();
            localStorage.setItem('localsystem', system );
        });
    });







    $(function () {
        $('input[system*="system"]').val(localStorage.getItem("localsystem"));
    });

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making these columns lookup columns? You'll just need to change "Request access" column a lookup column and you should be able to pull in all the other columns.
[image]

Comment: This might be your answer than. The question was quite similar.  
[Auto Populate data from one SP form to another SP form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/262500/auto-populate-data-from-one-sp-form-to-another-sp-form/262510#262510)
That's how a pass data to a different form.

Comment: Hi Jaitsujin, I am new to Jquery. Could you please share the code for above request.

Comment: Please see updated code version [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/262500/auto-populate-data-from-one-sp-form-to-another-sp-form/262510#262510).

Comment: You'll have to split the two examples. Use the first snippet on your new form in list one and the second part in list two. I tested and it works fine.  Would you be able to send screenshots?

Comment: As suggested split the script two part, its working, thanks. we want one more column data also need to fetch i.e column name is "Data Owner" and column type as "Person or group". So when we click on link column, it need to fetch data of "Title" and "Data Owner" column to new list form.

Comment: Added script on two form, but its title column picking latest added item name when we click on the link. Suppose if two or three items added on the list and when click on "Access" column, its takes to new form and title name taking latest added item tile name. Please suggest

Comment: To add another column just simply create another localStorage the same way you did with the title column. Just replace it with your other columns title.  e.g.:
**localStorage.setItem('localDataOwner', dataOwner);**

Comment: You'll have to make sure you name localStorages differently.  localStorage.setItem('**localTitle**', title );