# Auto populate column data from one list form to another list form in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, jquery, splistitem

We had two lists in SharePoint 2013. One list (Report) is for the report and another list (Access) for access.

First list "Report" consist of a different column, one column name as "Request access" with Hyperlink column. So when user clicks on "Request access" column it will take to "Access" list.

Now our requirement, Access list columns need to auto populate data from "Report" register list. Means suppose we have columns with name as "Request', "Title", "owner names". Those columns data need to auto populate on "Access" list.

Is there any code for my request instead of lookup column?
I am trying this code, but data not getting populated. Could anyone correct me?

Added below jquery script on the script editor under Report list

-- New form source of Report list --

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>'
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('input[Request*="Request"]').on("change paste keyup", function() {
            var Audience = $('[id*="Request"]').val();
            localStorage.setItem('localRequest', Request );
        });
    });
</script>
```

-- New form destination on Access list --

Adding jquery script on the Destination list(Access) for populating data from Report list.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('input[Text*="Text"]').val(localStorage.getItem("localServiceArea"));
    });
</script>
```

---

Please share correct code or update in correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the same issue as previously?

[Auto Populate data from one SP form to another SP form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/262500/auto-populate-data-from-one-sp-form-to-another-sp-form/262510#262510)

Just to clarify. You do know that you have to add these scripts to the forms directly. not to the list.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jaitsujin for correct me in right direction. But when i apply the script, i am getting data of latest added item. means Suppose if i added item name as "Jaitsujin" and Destination source list also getting same name as "Jaitsujjin". but After that if i create new item name as "Murali" and destination source getting "Murali" name, but i click on "Jaitsujjin" column again, its getting name as "Murali". Means latest data populating for previous items. Hope you got understand my issue. Could you please suggest for same.

Comment: Dear Jaitsujin, could please help on above issue.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your setup?

Comment: Means list view screenshot?

Comment: Is this the behavior you're looking to achieve?
[scrennrecording](https://vimeo.com/335762479)

Comment: sorry i am not getting u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93572/discussion-between-jaitsujin-and-murali-kuruva).